# "Regression" in a positive sense

Tags: synonyms, connotation

I'm looking for a word that means returning to the past or embracing old values, but words like "regression," "retrogression," and "atavism" all seem to have negative connotations attached to them.

Is there such a word that means "regression" in a positive sense?

Comment: Perhaps "conservative" or "traditionalist"?  The problem, as I see it, is that regression, et al. carry a connotation of moving backwards.  However (and correct me if I'm wrong), you're trying to positively express the adoption of traditional values.

Comment: I'm trying to use the word in context of the Renaissance, where going back to ancient times and embracing Classical works/values became popular.

Comment: 'Restoration' doesn't seem to have negative connotations (for the process).

Comment: *Regression* itself is positive, if it is regression from something negative. Regression of a cancerous growth is a good thing.

Comment: If you are trying to use the word in the context of the Renaissance, then how about "Renaissance" itself, meaning rebirth?

Answer (score 3):

You might call this a **revival** of the old value, or a **return to form**.

Comment: Amusingly enough, this answer earned me the revival badge.

Answer (score 0):

since you mentioned the word embracing, you could simply say "re-embracing" other alternatives might include "returning to [innocence, your youth, your culture, your values, your real self ] "